# "I can't well start a day" vs. "I can't start a day well"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

> - I can't **well** start a day not running at least a few kilometres.
> - I can't start a day **well** not running at least a few kilometres.

Comment: I may be wrong, but this would likely depend on where you live (UK vs. USA, for example).  I know that, for me living in the USA, I would say "I can't start a day well..." but I could definitely see this being arranged the other way too.  Another thing I might look at would be to reword the sentence a little.  Maybe something along the lines of "I can't start a day well, _without_ running..."

Answer (score 2):

> I can’t start a day **well** without going running.

This means that you can’t have a good start to your day unless you go running. Here, “well” modifies “start”. I think this is what you mean to say.

> I can’t [very] **well** start a day without going running.

This means that you think it would be rather absurd to start your day without going running. Here, “well” (or “very well”) modifies “can’t”. You often see this in rhetorical questions:

> I can’t very well go running with a broken leg, now can I?

Comment: +1 I think your suggestion of adding/imagining the "[very]" before "well" is certainly enough by itself to clarify what that sentence means/how to parse it.   With the "very" actually added, one could perhaps even add/imagine "[be expected to]" after "well." (but I'm not good enough in grammar to know how that added passive phrase would parse)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't start a day well without going running.

This implies that you will not have a good start if you don't run first. "Well" in this situation modifies "start". The above sentence is also equivalent to this one:

> The day will not start well if I don't start running.